# How can I get the bash $RANDOM in a makefile?

Tags: bash, makefile

This works on OSX:

```
RANDOM := $(shell /bin/bash -c "echo $$RANDOM")

test:
    echo $(RANDOM)
```

For cross platform random numbers I've instead resorted to this:

```
RANDOM := $(shell od -An -N2 -i /dev/random | tr -d ' ')
```

How can I get the first example to work?

Answer (score 3):

The reason your first line works on OSX and not Ubuntu, is likely because sh is bash on OSX. `$$RANDOM` is already expanded by the time the bash -c gets around to executing it, since you used `""` quotes. So you probably want this:

```
RANDOM := $(shell bash -c 'echo $$RANDOM')
```

Personally I'd probably go with awk. Something like

```
awk 'BEGIN{srand();printf("%d", 65536*rand())}'
```